# How do I configure the timezone info in loopback?

Tags: mysql, loopbackjs

I have been looking for this like since the last 2 - 3 hrs. Still I can't figure out how. I need to set it up as UTC+07 I see an option to specify it in the datasources.json

```
"mydb": { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 3306, "database": "mydb", "username": "root", "password": "root", "name": "mydb", "connector": "mysql", "timezone": "UTC+07:00" }
```

It seems to have no effect.

I have two fields (date_add and date_upd) in a table. Also I am using this package "loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin": "^3.2.2", to map these fields as a mixin

I have checked this link [Strongloop How to config mysql timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003166/strongloop-how-to-config-mysql-timezone)
and it's not working :)

node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js

```
function MySQL(settings) {
    ......
    var options = {
        host: s.host || s.hostname || 'localhost',
        port: s.port || 3306,
        user: s.username || s.user,
        password: s.password,
        timezone: s.timezone,
        socketPath: s.socketPath,
        charset: s.collation.toUpperCase(), // Correct by docs despite seeming odd.
        supportBigNumbers: s.supportBigNumbers,
        connectionLimit: s.connectionLimit
      };
    .....
}
```

not quite sure if it's the correct script though :)

If it's not possible via the datasource configuration do you know how can we specify the timezone config for the application?

Comment: I assume you restarted the app, right?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still the same issue though.

Comment: Are you sure it is supported? From the official docs, it looks like no: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/MySQL+connector

Comment: That's strange. I see an option for this here. Please check the updated question.

Comment: I'd argue that if it isn't documented, it isn't supported. :) Sorry - that's all I got.

Comment: :) Just wondering if it's not possible via the datasource configuration do you know how can we specify the timezone config for the application?

Comment: Looks supported here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/MySQL-connector.html#properties